# Getting Windows NT user information in a Spring WebFlow Project

Tags: java, windows, spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

I am working on a Spring WebFlow Project and the firm is asking to remove the login process and somehow just get the windows NT user from the workstation.

Does anyone know of any way to do this?

Please help me out..

Comment: I think you're using Spring Security, correct? If so, this will be a question for that tag, I believe. I haven't done it myself, but I'm guessing there's a Spring Security implementation which uses Windows authentication.

Comment: yes I am using Spring Secuirty but I dont see anyway to get the NT user from workstation

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is [NTLM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTLM), a quick search revealed this blog entry: http://blog.mediasoft.be/ntlm-with-spring-security-20